# How to add a custom error hander for node / express

Tags: node.js, express

I have read the [express docs about error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) and am trying to add a custom handler for errors, but it never gets called. app.ts:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const app = express ();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
// Configuring body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('my handler')
})
....
....
```

Here's a function with a deliberate error:

```
export function getRidesForDate(request: { body: { data: number; }; }, response: { json: (arg0: Ride[] ) => void; }, next: (arg0: { code: any; }) => void) {
    const date = request.body.data;
    const sql = `incorrect query`;
     
    dbconnection.query(sql,function (error: { code: any; }, results: Ride[])
    {
        if (error != null) {
          next(error);
        }
        response.json(results);
      });
    }
```

The error is caught and the server doesn't crash, which is great. But the overridden error handler `app.use((err, req, res, next)` is not called - the full error stack is output the the server console, and I want to return something meaningful to the client.

Comment: You must declare the global error handler `app.use((err, req, res, next)` as the last middleware to catch errors in all middleware before it.

Comment: `if (error != null) { ... } else { response.json(results); }`

Comment: @eekinci yes that's better logic - but doesn't help the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @AhmedKhairy yes you're correct, I guess I didn't fully understand 'middleware' , The handler needs to go after `app.listen`, `app.post` etc. The express doc that  I linked to doesn't make that clear in its example.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't really understand the term 'middleware'!  The docs I linked to don't include `app.post` etc in the examples.

I found a good explanation [here](https://dev.to/qbentil/how-to-write-custom-error-handler-middleware-in-expressjs-using-javascript-29j1)

```
const app = express ();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
// Configuring body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("RideHub server listening on PORT:", port);
});
app.post(..);
app.get(...);

// and last-of-all !
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.message);
  //todo: also add to log file
  res.statusMessage = err.message;
  res.status(500).send(err.message)
})
```

still not sure though how to get the content of `send(err.message)` at the client, `res` doesn't include it so I have changed the `statusMessage`